# Monitor turns blank when installing ubuntu on RBP4

Tags: ubuntu

need advice!

I am trying to install ubuntu20.04 64-bit server on RBP4 8G with 32G microSD.
I followed installation instructions mentioned on the raspberry official website, i.e.

1. Installed **Raspberry Pi Imager for Windows** on my laptop
2. On the imager, selected Ubuntu20.04 64-bit server as OS, and D: drive (i.e. microSD) as storage.
3. **Ctrl+Shift+x** to set SSH to enabled and set wifi network name and password, and **Save**.
4. Then click **Write** to start transferring image to the microSD.
5. Writing and verifying were completed without problem.
6. When transfer was completed, a pop-up said need to format E: drive. I clicked "cancel" (Even I clicked "format", it said "E: drive cannot be formatted") because I assumed this portion was not important, and went ahead with the next step.
7. Removed the microSD from the laptop and inserted into the RBP4, which has keyboard, mouse, ethernet cable and HDMI monitor connected.
8. RBP4 was then powered up and activities were shown on the monitor. However, a while later, the monitor turned blank and the GREEN LED on the RBP4 has totally stopped blinking!!

Pls refer to **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUDFnH7Pt-I**

Not sure if I have missed out any steps in between. Please advise.

**By the way, the RBP4 is working as it can be booted up with a pre-installed raspbian OS.**

Comment: I stopped reading at step 3. This only works for Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: It worked already :))